# How to Locally Setup Magento Enterprise Cloud Edition

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, installation, magento2-enterprise, cloud

I am working on a new project where the client has taken subscription of Magento Enterprise Cloud Edition.

I know that Magento Enterprise Cloud Edition enables us to use the following three types of environments, i.e. integration, staging, and production.

I have its account access like [image]

I took its clone on locally and try to do installation through "composer install" like we do in CE. but its ended on error

> File doesn't exist: bin/magento Check "chmod" section in composer.json
>   of magento/magento2-base package. File doesn't exist: bin/magento
>   Check "chmod" section in composer.json of magento/magento2-ee-base
>   package.

I donot know whats the right way of doing its local setup. Enterprice is a new environment for me. Kindly guide me it would be a great favour.

Comment: File doesn't exist: `bin/magento`

Comment: I have also the same issue in my current cloud project. While composer update command it throws the same error as above.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem while setting up the Magento Cloud Edition on the local machine. While running the `composer update` I was getting the above error.

It seems to be some kind of configuration error or some composer related issue. There is a trace of the same issue on the Magento Forum and on Magento2 Github Issue tracker.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4792#issuecomment-352069900

I have solved the issue by downgrading and upgrading the Magento version using `composer.json` file.

Downgrade the version to 2.2.2 and upgrade again to the 2.2.3. After this, I am able to run composer upgrade and install the Magento Cloud on the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step process is given on this [link in Magento devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/access-acct/first-time-setup.html) to create a local environment of Magento enterprise cloud edition. Please refer.